# Load IE symbols in Immunity Debugger

Tags: immunity-debugger, debugging-symbols

I know Immdbg already recognizes Windows internals function names, like kernel32.dll and user32.dll

What I want is to load Internet Explorer symbols the same way WinDbg does. Does someone knows it is possible, like mshtml.dll?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Immunity Debugger 1.60 and above supports loading of PDB Symbol files both locally or from a symbol server. In order to enable it.

1. Go to *Debug* menu -> *Debugging Symbol Options*.

[image]

2. Provide the local path to the symbol files or to a symbol server.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

If ImmDbg successfully loaded the pdb symbol for the specified file, you would get a message in the logs in the form `Debugging Information (DIA Format) available` below the dll loading event. See the image below for reference.

[image]

If even after all this, you cannot load the appropriate symbol for a file, then

1. You may have misconfigured the symbol path.
2. In case of local symbol, the PDB file present on the system does not match with the PE.
3. In case of symbol server, appropriate PDB file could not be found.

In such a case you can run the *symcheck* tool provided with windbg. Example usage

```
C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)>symchk C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll /s C:\WINDOWS\Symbols

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 0
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 1

C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)>symchk C:\WINDOWS\system32\mshtml.dll /s C:\WINDOWS\Symbols
SYMCHK: mshtml.dll           FAILED  - mshtml.pdb mismatched or not found

SYMCHK: FAILED files = 1
SYMCHK: PASSED + IGNORED files = 0
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

Screenshot of Immunity Debugger with symbols for *mshtml.dll* loaded. This is taken from Windows XP SP3.

[image]

**Other Info**: ImmDbg could not download symbols from the MS Symbol Server, so had to use the symcheck tool to download symbol for *mshtml.dll* .

```
symchk /r c:\windows\system32\mshtml.dll /s SRV*c:\symbols\*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
```

The symbol directory should look like this.

```
C:\symbols>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 042A-A7E6

 Directory of C:\symbols

06/05/2015  12:39 PM    <DIR>          .
06/05/2015  12:39 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/15/2008  09:21 AM         7,965,696 mshtml.pdb
06/05/2015  11:17 AM                 0 pingme.txt
```

Next, pointed ImmDbg to `C:\symbols\`. Used *loaddll* to load *mshtml.dll* and it automatically picked up the symbol on loading. This can also be seen in the logs.

[image]

Comment: Just a note, you can also download the symbol file from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028.aspx).

Comment: I've already done this however look at the image I've updated in my question... the functions name are not shown

Comment: @jyz What does ImmDbg log says? If it indeed loaded the pdb file it would be written in the logs as `Debugging Information (DIA Format) available` below the dll loading event.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders I tried again, again but this message is not shown. Also, When I start \Program Files(x86)\Microsoft Internet Explorer\iexplorer.exe and navigate `mshtml.dll` is never loaded! I'm checking in `ALT+E` and `ALT+L` modules... any idea?

Comment: @jyz See updated answer. Try to load *mshtml.dll* with *loaddll*

Comment: @ExtremeCoders thanks for updated answer. It seems that ImmDbg cannot download remote symbols, at least not for me. I had to manually download the symbols

Comment: @ExtremeCoders Whould you mind paste an screenshot with mshtml symbols loaded in ImmDbg, please?

Comment: @jyz You can use the symcheck tool to [manually download](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311503) the symbols, put it in a local symbol folder, point ImmDbg to it and it should load it automatically. Additionally the symbol support in ImmDbg seems to be immature, so you may encounter problems.

Comment: @jyz See update 2.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders This tip with `symchk` really solved my problem! Thanks man!